# SED copy specific section to different files

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I've tried to create a script which saves my time.
This is what I want to do:
I have one big .xml file with sections, let's say it looks like this:

```
some text
.....
HEAD
context A
TAIL
some text
.....
HEAD
context B
TAIL
....
some text
....
HEAD
context C
TAIL
....
some text
```

I need to cut section with `context A` and move to file contextA, then `context B` to file contextB, and so on. (All files should contain syntax `HEAD context x TAIL`)
The problem is that all contexts start and end in the same regex (HEAD and TAIL).
I can cut all section to one file but it's not enough.

Can you help me?

It's a little update because maybe I'm not clarified it enough:
Let say my file looks like that:

```
 some text 1
 <config>
 1
 2
 3
 </config>
 some text 2
 <config>
 4
 5
 6
 </config>
 some text 3
 <config>
 7
 8
 9
 </config>
 some text 4
```

and I want file named:

"first" which contain:

```
 <config>
 1
 2
 3
 </config>
```

"second"  which contain:

```
 <config>
 4
 5
 6
 </config>
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is easier to do this with awk:

```bash
awk -v RS="HEAD\n" -v FS="\n" 'NR>1{print "HEAD\n" $0 > $1".txt"}' ex
```

Notes:

- `RS="HEAD\n"` registers are separated by "HEAD\n"
- `FS="\n"`   each field is a line
- `NR>1{print "HEAD\n" $0 > $1}`  for all register except the first, write it to a file named field 1 -- "$1"

UPDATE: for the new question:

```
awk -v RS="<config>\n" -F"</config>" 'NR>1{print RS $1 FS > "conf-"NR-1}' ex
```

The configuration outputs are stored in files named like: "conf-1"

Answer (score 1):

**If you really can't use a proper XML parser for this**, then I'd suggest `awk` e.g.

```
awk '/^HEAD/ {p=1; ++n} p {print > "context"n} /^TAIL/ {p=0}' file.xml
```

will output the `HEAD` ... `TAIL` sections into numerically increasing filenames `context1`, `context2` etc.

For easier sorting, you may want to improve it a bit by constructing a fixed-width numeric prefix e.g.

```
$ awk '/^HEAD/ {p=1; outfile = sprintf("context%03d", ++n)} p {print > outfile} /^TAIL/ {p=0}' file.xml

$ head context*
==> context001 <==
HEAD
context A
TAIL

==> context002 <==
HEAD
context B
TAIL

==> context003 <==
HEAD
context C
TAIL
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether below script helps you :

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for x in {A..Z}; do
    # check if the pattern exists in the file
    if grep -qF "context $x" file.txt; then
        # Store the lines between the 2 patterns including the matching lines in a text file
        awk '/context '$x'/,/TAIL/' file.txt > context$x.txt
    else
       echo "Sorry this pattern does not exists in file"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly not. "context x" is for example. Context A and B are different so i cannot look for "context. I want to find first start and end section (HEAD and TAIL) move this section to some file and after that i want to find second section, move to another file and so on

Answer (score 0):

My script using `awk`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for i in $(seq -w $(<"$1" grep -cx "$2")); do
  <"$1" >$i awk -va=$i -vb="$2" -vc="$3" '$0~b{d++;e=1}d==a&&e==1;$0~c{e=0}'
done
```

Save it as e.g. `myscript.sh`, make it executable, navigate to your `onebig.xml` and call it like this:

```
/path/to/myscript.sh onebig.xml HEAD TAIL
```

It will cut out every section from `onebig.xml` beginning with `HEAD` and ending with `TAIL` and save them as `1`, `2`, … if there are less than 10 sections, as `01`, `02`, … if there are 10 to 99 sections, as `001`, `002`, … if there are 100 to 999 sections and so forth.

#### Short explanations

- `<"$1" grep -cx "$2"` – count occurences of `HEAD` in `onebig.xml`, let's say that's `3`
- `for i in $(seq -w 3); do …; done` – loop over every occurence from 1 to `3`, `seq`'s`-w` option adds trailing zeroes if necessary
- `<"$1" >$i` – read from `onebig.xml` and write to a file named like the current count
- `awk -va=$i -vb="$2" -vc="$3"` – start `awk` and assign three variables, `a` being the count, `b` being `HEAD` and `c` being `TAIL`
- `$0~b{d++;e=1}` – if the current line contains the content of `b` (= `HEAD`) increase `d` by one and set `e=1`
- `d==a&&e==1` – if `d` equals `a` (= the current count) and `e` equals `1` then print the current line (`print` is the implied action; essentially that's: if it's after the `a`th occurence of `HEAD` and we're between `HEAD` and `TAIL` then print)
- `$0~c{e=0}` – if the current line contains the content of `c` (= `TAIL`) set `e=0`

Comment: Unfortunatelly: ./sec.txt: line 2:   syntax error near unexpected token `$'do\r''
'/sec.txt: line 2: `for i in $(seq -w $(<"$1" grep -cx "$2")); do

Comment: seq, grep and awk installed are installed.
in my xml file HEAD is <begin> and TAIL is </begin>. My bash script is named as sec.txt

Comment: I've called: `./sec.txt q.xml '<config>' '</config>'` because I want to search for this regex. sec.txt is a script, q.xml is an xml file, and two parameters

Comment: I've copied it once again to new file and it works only if I change `<config>...</config>` to `start.... end` (only for testing in xml file). It looks like "<", ">", and "/" characters are not recognizable

Comment: @TomM The `$'\r'` indicates you saved the file with Windows-style line endings. Save it again with Unix-style.